# Issue while inserting files in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I am facing a lot of issue while storing file in hdfs. File stored in **HDFS** is having binary values and timestamp. I am trying to remove it but not able to do it. Please help

**Result :**

`000000: 46 48 50 7c b3 7e 5c 26 7c 4c 33 1d 43 7c MHS|1^&@|fff 000010:`

**Expected :**

```
MHS|1^&@|fff 000010
```

**Code :**

```
 hadoop fs -put localpath hdfspath
```

Comment: Are you logged as SuperAdmin (sa) ?

Comment: Can you pls post some sample what you are seeing vs what's expected. And more specifically the commands you are using and the format of files

Comment: @SurjanSRawat i have updated my question please check.

Comment: @Mohamed2a no i am not logged as SuperAdmin.

Comment: You can manipulate your file, there is not problem. Under Hue, you can display the text instead of binary value.

Comment: @Mohamed2a how to select that option can you please tell me.

Comment: open the content of your file under Hue then you find the option in the left menu bar

Comment: @Mohamed2a Thanks it worked, but i can see some symbols like `��`. How can i see actual data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Apache Hue web interface, open the content of your file then you find the option to display the content in text format in the left menu bar